# Score++ doesnt work

Tags: java, int

I am trying to add score when the button is pressed,the score is displayed in the JTextField, but when the button is pressed the score inst added, it says 0.
I have an integer field which stores the score

```
private int score=0;

yesButton = new JButton("True");
panel.add(yesButton);
yesButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    int index = 0;
    @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        index++;
        score++;
        qScore.setText("",+score);
        qText.setText(questions.get(index).getQuestions());  
    }
});
```

score

```
JPanel scorePanel = new JPanel();
        scorePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0));
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Score:");
        JTextField qScore = new JTextField(); 
        qScore.setEditable(false);
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How about posting the entire class?

Comment: And have you debugged the code when the yes button is pressed?

Comment: Have you debugged the actionPerformed method?

Comment: no.. but the code compiles and i dont see any errors

Comment: Why is qScore read only?

Comment: because i dont want people to touch the score..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `actionPerformed` method, you're not updating the view with the new score. I imagine it will be something like:

```
score.setText("Score:" + score);
```

Comment: i tried that.. doesnt work.. sheck my edit i posted my code for score

Comment: Hello, i updated my code.. but i get an error cannot be applied to given types

Comment: Why are you declaring a new `JTextField` for the score. The `JTextField` needs to exist on the page. You're changing it's `text` property using `setText()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable qScore should be an instance member and constructed once.

Then when the actionPerformed method is fired, call setText

```
// in actionPerformed
score++;
qScore.setText(score);
```

Comment: Hello!, thank you for your reply, but i get action cannot be applied to this given type when i try that

Comment: method setText in class javax.swing.text.JTextComponenet cannot be applied to give types... reason actual and formal argument lists differ in length